# Update variable while reading in files in R loop

Tags: r, loops

I am reading multiple txt files and I would like to remove the first row and save it as a variable, transpose it and later when I'm done doing stuff I would like to save it along with other variables in a file.

The problem is that my code is just saving the first txt information and repeating it for the rest of the txt files.

My code:

```
    for(i in 1:length(filesW))
{
  data <- read.table(paste0("data",i,".txt", sep=""), sep=",", header=TRUE)
  winstepsdat2 <- data.frame(data)


  genparameter<-t((winstepsdat2[1,]))
  winstepsdat<-winstepsdat2[-1,]

  num_col<-ncol(winstepsdat)
  num_row<-nrow(winstepsdat)

  colnames(winstepsdat) <- paste("i", 1:num_col, sep="")
  winstepsdat$name<- paste ("p", 1:num_row, sep="")

  #must change ni and labels for 1:n??
  cmd <- wcmd(title = "R2Winsteps Example", data=paste0("data",i,".txt"),item1 = 1, ni =num_col , name1 = 30, namelen = 20,labels = paste('i',                                                                                                                                1:num_col, sep = ""), hlines = "Y" ) #codes=1:5

  write.wdat(winstepsdat, cmd)

  write.wcmd(cmd, paste0("CMFILE[",i,"].cmd"))

  winsteps2(cmd, outfile=paste0("outfile[",i,"].txt"), pfile=paste0("pfile",i,".txt"), ifile=paste0("ifile",i,".txt"), windir="C:/Winsteps/Winsteps.exe")

} #end for
```

Somehow winstepsdat does change as I go through text files (given that I get different values for other calculations, but genparameter just keeps the first txt file values. How can I store/save genparameter for every text file I read?

I'm a beginner programmer so I would appreciate the help. Thanks, Shmy

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but I am guessing that what you need is to initialize the variables (for instance, as lists), and then fill the list with the for loop.

Something like:

```
genparameter = list()
winstepsdat = list()
for(i in 1:length(filesW)) #i don't know what the length(filesW) was doing here
{
 data <- read.table(paste0("data",i,".txt", sep=""), sep=",", header=TRUE)
winstepsdat2 <- data.frame(data)

genparameter[[i]]<-t((winstepsdat2[1,])
winstepsdat[[i]] <-winstepsdat2[-1,]

...
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is trying to do, but I do think it's what OP **should** do :)

Comment: @Eudald, thank you but sadly it didn't work. When I read the first text file the values do not get updated as the loop continues through the next text file. length (filesW) goes through my files that's how long I want the loop to me :)

Comment: Mmmm, I see... Can you give me the whole function and what you expect it to do? Then I might understand better what the problem is.

Comment: @Eudald, Yes, I updated my post with the whole code (because the comment section warned me I had too many characters). Basically, I don't know why the loop doesn't go beyond the first text file. Thank you for trying!

Comment: What is filesW? Have you checked that its length exists and it's bigger than 1? (I know it sounds stupid but these kind of things often happen to me...)

Comment: @Eudald hi, its the number of files saved in the folder. I used filesW <- list.files() and yes, it's bigger than 1 :(

Comment: Ok, this is getting complicated. What I would do is try to debug it. [Here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#entering-debug-mode-stopping) you have instructions on how to do it. Remember that the debugger doesn't work in a markdown, you'll have to do it in a script file. Set breakpoints after every step and check what's going on with you files. I hope this helps!